# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) react-native-sms

Tags: react-native, sms

I am currently trying to use [react-native-sms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms) and am getting the **Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)** error. I believe this is caused by not handling the error messages correctly and primarily due to not knowing how to use the **catch** functionality. I've read other SO posts on how to handle this error but none specific to this scenario. And I am not using an emulator, I am using my actual device. If you can make any suggestions on how to fix this, that'd be amazing. Thank you so much for your help.Here is the code:

```
someFunction() {

    SendSMS.send({
        body: 'The default body of the SMS!',
        recipients: ['0123456789', '9876543210'],
        successTypes: ['sent', 'queued'],
        allowAndroidSendWithoutReadPermission: true
    }, (completed, cancelled, error) => {

        console.log('SMS Callback: completed: ' + completed + ' cancelled: ' + cancelled + 'error: ' + error);

    });
}
```

Comment: You have to link the library properly and have to add permission for android that is how you can solve the issue. Can you please take the help from here https://aboutreact.com/send-text-sms-in-react-native/

Answer (score 0):

If the `(completed, cancelled, error) =>` callback signature is right, you're probably just supposed to test if `error` exists, not catch it. For example:

```
SendSMS.send({
    body: 'The default body of the SMS!',
    recipients: ['123456789'], //used real phone number here.
    successTypes: ['sent', 'queued'],
    allowAndroidSendWithoutReadPermission: true
}, (completed, cancelled, error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } else {
      console.log('SMS Callback: completed: ' + completed);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but it's still giving me that same error.